# Проблема в создании метода внесения данных в БД mySQL Hibernate Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, spring, hibernate

```html
package com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "semestr")
public class Semestr {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "duration")
    private String duration;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status = true;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "semestr_discipline",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_semestr"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_discipline")
    )
    private List<Discipline> disciplineList;


    public void addDisciplineToSemester(Discipline discipline) {
        if (disciplineList == null) {
            disciplineList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        disciplineList.add(discipline);
    }

    public Semestr() {
    }

    public Semestr(int id, String name, String duration, boolean status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Discipline> getDisciplineList() {
        return disciplineList;
    }

    public void setDisciplineList(List<Discipline> disciplineList) {
        this.disciplineList = disciplineList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Semestr semestr = (Semestr) o;

        if (id != semestr.id) return false;
        if (status != semestr.status) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(semestr.name) : semestr.name != null) return false;
        return duration != null ? duration.equals(semestr.duration) : semestr.duration == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (duration != null ? duration.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (status ? 1 : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Semestr{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", duration='" + duration + '\'' +
                ", status=" + status +
                '}';
    }
}



package com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;


@Entity
@Table(name = "discipline")
public class Discipline {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "discipline")
    private String discipline;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status = true;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "semestr_discipline",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_discipline"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_semestr")
    )
    private List<Semestr> semestrList;

    public void addSemesterToDiscipline(Semestr semestr) {
        if (semestrList == null) {
            semestrList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        semestrList.add(semestr);
    }

    public Discipline() {

    }


    public Discipline(int id, String discipline, boolean status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.discipline = discipline;
        this.status = status;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDiscipline() {
        return discipline;
    }

    public void setDiscipline(String discipline) {
        this.discipline = discipline;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Semestr> getSemestrList() {
        return semestrList;
    }

    public void setSemestrList(List<Semestr> semestrList) {
        this.semestrList = semestrList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Discipline that = (Discipline) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                status == that.status &&
                Objects.equals(discipline, that.discipline);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, discipline, status);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Discipline{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", discipline='" + discipline + '\'' +
                ", status=" + status +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```js
package com.kushnirmark.spring.project.DAO;

import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Discipline;
import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Semestr;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
@Repository
public class SemestrImpl implements SemestrDAO{


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public List<Semestr> getSemestr() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Semestr> semestrs = session.createQuery("from Semestr" , Semestr.class).getResultList();
        return semestrs;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Discipline> getDisciplineSemestr() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Discipline>discSem = session.createQuery("select a.discipline from Discipline a" +
                " inner join Semestr_Disc b on a.id=b.id_discipline where b.id_semestr = 1 ").getResultList();
        return discSem;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveNewSemester(Semestr semestr) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(semestr);
    }

}





    @RequestMapping("/allSemestrs")
    public String allSemestrs(Model model) {
        List<Semestr> semestr = service.getSemestr();
        model.addAttribute("semestr", semestr);
        List<Discipline> allDisciplines = service.getDisciplineSemestr();
        model.addAttribute("allDisc", allDisciplines);
        return "semestr";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/creteNewSemester")
    public String creteNewSemester(Model model) {
        Semestr semestr = new Semestr();
        model.addAttribute("semestr", semestr);
        List<Discipline> allDisciplines = service.getAllDisciplines();
        model.addAttribute("allDisc", allDisciplines);
        return "create-semestr";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/saveNewSemester")
    public String saveNewSemester(@ModelAttribute("semestr") Semestr semestr) {
        service.saveNewSemester(semestr);
        return "redirect:/semestr";
    }
```

```css
package com.kushnirmark.spring.project.service;

import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.DAO.DisciplinesDAO;
import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.DAO.SemestrDAO;
import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.DAO.StudentsDAO;
import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Discipline;
import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Semestr;
import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Student;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {


    @Autowired
    private StudentsDAO studentsDAO;

    @Autowired
    private DisciplinesDAO disciplinesDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SemestrDAO semestrDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return studentsDAO.getAllStudents();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        studentsDAO.saveStudent(student);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Student getStudent(int id) {
        return studentsDAO.getStudent(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteStudent(int id) {
        studentsDAO.deleteStudent(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Discipline> getAllDisciplines() {

        return disciplinesDAO.getAllDisciplines();

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveDiscipline(Discipline discipline) {
        disciplinesDAO.saveDiscipline(discipline);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Discipline getDiscipline(int id) {
        return disciplinesDAO.getDiscipline(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteDiscipline(int id) {
        disciplinesDAO.deleteDiscipline(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Semestr> getSemestr() { return semestrDAO.getSemestr(); }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Discipline> getDisciplineSemestr() {
        return semestrDAO.getDisciplineSemestr();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveNewSemester(Semestr semestr) {
        semestrDAO.saveNewSemester(semestr);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    package com.kushnirmark.spring.project.DAO;

import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Discipline;
import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Semestr;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
@Repository
public class SemestrImpl implements SemestrDAO{


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public List<Semestr> getSemestr() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Semestr> semestrs = session.createQuery("from Semestr" , Semestr.class).getResultList();
        return semestrs;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Discipline> getDisciplineSemestr() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Discipline>discSem = session.createQuery("select a.discipline from Discipline a" +
                " inner join Semestr_Disc b on a.id=b.id_discipline where b.id_semestr = 1 ").getResultList();
        return discSem;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveNewSemester(Semestr semestr) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(semestr);
    }
```

Столкнулся с такой проблемой :Пытаюсь создать семестр который связан с дисциплинами , но не содержит их как поле класса. Есть связующая таблица где пересекаются их id id_semestr / id_discipline как мне это можно реализовать ? Пытаюсь реализовать все в Hibernate Spring MVC mySQL. Не понимаю как правильно должен быть создан запрос для корректного создания. Извиняюсь сразу за не очень внятный вопрос , надеюсь меня можно понять

```html
 <form:form action="saveNewSemester" modelAttribute="semestr">

        <tr>

            <td width="210px">Semester name</td>

            <td><form:input path="name"/></td>

        </tr>
        <br>
        <tr>

            <td width="210px">Duration (in weeks)</td>

            <td><form:input path="duration"/></td>

        </tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px" valign="top">Disciplines in a semester</td>
            <td style="padding-top: 30px">

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 0"><select multiple size="6" name="AllDiscipline"
                                                       id="multi_list" multiple="multiple">


                            <c:forEach items="${allDisc}" var="d">

                                <option value="${d.id}">${d.discipline}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top: 20px">

                            <input type="submit" value="Create">
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>
                </form:form>
                </form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос про то как создать запрос, а в описании верстка и скриншот веб-страницы. Это отвечающим никак не поможет. Сущности и DAO / Репозитории семестра и дисциплины приложите, пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня сегодня уже сил не хватит написать ответ. Завтра если время будет - постараюсь ответить.

Comment: Постарайтесь к этому времени соответствующие исходники приложить.

Comment: Если ждать будет невтерпеж, то можете почитать про то как реализовывать связь МНОГИЕ-КО-МНОГИМ в hibernate https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

Comment: в целом, можно выбирать на свой вкус по запросу Hibernate Many to Many в Google: https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=hibernate+many+to+many

Comment: Добавил сущности , ДАО , СЕРВИС... голову уже сломал как мне написать этот метод , из формы jstl не получается тоже взять id семестра , короче большая проблема в этом понимании. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Comment: Мне хотя бы разобраться каким образом я могу получить id дисциплин при мульти выборе , это уже очень сильно мне поможет